Put stars (asterisks) on Vega or Vega-Lite bar plots that represent significance comparisons
Similar to Put stars on ggplot barplots and boxplots - to indicate the level of significance (p-value), I'm interested if there's a way to put some marks on a vega plot that represent the significance comparison.
Here's an example of what the final chart would look like:

An example spec that gets partially there:
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A bar chart with significance indicators",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"group": "DMSO", "value": 1.0},
      {"group": "Compound 1", "value": 0.4},
      {"group": "Compound 2", "value": 0.55}
    ]
  },
  "width": 300,
  "height": 200,
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "group", "type": "nominal", "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}},
        "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"field": "group", "type": "nominal"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "fontSize": 14, "dy": -5},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "group", "type": "nominal"},
        "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
        "text": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative", "format": ".2f"}
      }
    },
    {
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {"x": "DMSO", "x2": "Compound 1", "y": 1.3, "label": "**"},
          {"x": "DMSO", "x2": "Compound 2", "y": 1.4, "label": "**"}
        ]
      },
      "mark": {"type": "rule"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "x", "type": "nominal"},
        "x2": {"field": "x2"},
        "y": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {"x": "Compound 1", "y": 1.32, "label": "**"},
          {"x": "Compound 2", "y": 1.42, "label": "**"}
        ]
      },
      "mark": {"type": "text", "fontSize": 16, "fontWeight": "bold"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "x", "type": "nominal"},
        "y": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative"},
        "text": {"field": "label"}
      }
    }
  ]
}

Produces this:


Yes that would be possible using Unichar characters in a text mark or svg in point shape for example. You need to setup a base spec with all other info and test data so we can test this. SO is not a free coding service.

Sure, edited the post to have an example spec which has the asterisks (that's not the hard part). The more challenging part for me is getting the lines above the bars to reach the exact middle of the bars and extend down slightly

You could just add some tick marks and set the orient to vertical.

{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "A bar chart with significance indicators",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"group": "DMSO", "value": 1},
      {"group": "Compound 1", "value": 0.4},
      {"group": "Compound 2", "value": 0.55}
    ]
  },
  "width": 300,
  "height": 200,
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "bar",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "group", "type": "nominal", "axis": {"labelAngle": 0}},
        "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {"field": "group", "type": "nominal"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "text", "fontSize": 13, "dy": -7},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "group", "type": "nominal"},
        "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
        "text": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative", "format": ".2f"}
      }
    },
    {
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {"x": "DMSO", "y": 1.4},
          {"x": "Compound 2", "y": 1.4},
          {"x": "Compound 1", "y": 1.25},
          {"x": "DMSO", "y": 1.25}
        ]
      },
      "mark": {
        "type": "tick",
        "orient": "vertical",
        "color": "black",
        "size": 7
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "x", "type": "nominal"},
        "y": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative"},
        "yOffset": {"value": 3}
      }
    },
    {
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {"x": "DMSO", "x2": "Compound 1", "y": 1.25, "label": "**"},
          {"x": "DMSO", "x2": "Compound 2", "y": 1.4, "label": "**"}
        ]
      },
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": {"type": "rule"},
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "x", "type": "nominal"},
            "x2": {"field": "x2"},
            "y": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative"}
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "fontSize": 16,
            "fontWeight": "bold",
            "xOffset": 10,
            "yOffset": -3
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "x2", "type": "nominal"},
            "y": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative"},
            "text": {"field": "label"}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


That's helpful, thank you! Any advice on how to center the asterisks?
